# Does MS-Project ODATA-Feed support Create, update or delete operations?

Tags: odata, ms-project

I'm talking about the MS-Project Online ODATA-Feed, described e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/office/project-odata/jj163015(v=office.15)
I can't find any information if the ODATA-Feed supports Create, update or delete operations? There are only read examples in the internet for the MS-project-odata-API.

Comment: As ODATA is reporting data, it should be read-only--changes to the data should be made in MS Project.

Comment: pls. see my own answer. ODATA seems not to be read-only always, here a comment from the MS-docs: 'You can also access Project Server functionality through the REST interface.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself now. MS Project hast two odata-APIs, the one I used before was **_api/ProjectData**. Use **_api/ProjectServer** instead and cud-operations are possible. The endpoints and thus the data you get is very different as well. Here is the documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj712612(v=office.15)